# How do I see my Elmah error log in production

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I have setup Elmah on my production website and it works fine when running on my machine. When deploying to production, I cannot see my log and I guess it is because of the settings in my config file:

```
<security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
```

How to access my log on this environment without having to open up for everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELMAH supports authorization on your error logs as described in this [ELMAH Tutorial](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/). In short, you need to configure ELMAH to only allow access to certain users or roles in your web.config:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
                 path="elmah.axd"
                 type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="admin" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ELMAH"
                 verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
                 path="elmah.axd"
                 type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"
                 preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This allows users with the admin role only. There's also some documentation on this in the ELMAH documentation on [this page](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages).